# How do I tell the difference between an 8Khz acoustic model and a 16Khz model?

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

I'm able to get a reasonable level of accuracy with 8khz audio files. Now I want to try a higher sample rate, if I can.

Looking at the acoustic models available on [this page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English%20Generic%20Acoustic%20Model/), they list:

```
en-us-8khz.tar.gz     
en-us-semi-full.tar.gz  
en-us-semi.tar.gz  
en-us.tar.gz
```

The one that says 8khz is obviously the one for the 8khz sample rate, but what about the other three? What sample rates do they match?

If I use a 16khz audio file, which of these acoustic models do I need to use?

And in the absense of the sample rate being in the file name, how do I figure out the sample rate of an acoustic model?

Comment: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam

Comment: @AlexanderSolovets Are you saying the answer is in there somewhere? SO is a site where hard-to-find knowledge can be bubbled up to the top. If it's in there, it's hard to find. Can you clearly post it so that it can be less hard to find for people in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the file feat.params in model folder and look for `-upperf` parameter. In 8khz model `-upperf` is usually 3500 or 4000. For 16khz model `-upperf` is more than 4000, usually 6800.